# Compare Date with PORO

Tags: ruby

I have implemented the null object pattern (with the `MissingDate` class)on a Ruby app to handle a specific case when a `Date` object is not available.

Now, I need to compare instances of `Date` and `MissingDate` and have `MissingDate` always bigger than `Date`. Therefore, I have included the `Comparable` module.

```rb
class MissingDate
  include Comparable

  ...

  def <=>(other)
    if [Date, MissingDate].include?(other.class)
      1
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

However, I get `comparison of Date with MissingDate failed`. What am I missing?

Comment: The method you defined is only called when you compare a missing_date with a date, but not when you compare a date with a missing_date (order is important here). In the second case (comparing date with a missing_date) the original implementation in Date would still be called.

Comment: Thanks. So, is it possible to compare the instances of the two classes?

Comment: That is possible. But to be able to you would need to override the method in the original `Date` class that comes with Ruby too. And I am not sure if that is a good idea and worth it because it can lead to unexpected results when you change the behavior of Ruby core methods.